# How to forward headers on HTTP redirect

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm writing a webapp that responses an HTTP redirect. Is there a way to force the client to forward the headers I include in the response to the new url?

Example request:

```
POST /insertion HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 9

(content)
```

Webapp response:

```
HTTP/1.x 302 Found
Location: /dock
Mydata: asdf
```

Next client request:

```
GET /dock HTTP/1.1
Mydata: asdf
```

Update: It seems I wasn't clear on the matter. I know cookies would be useful, but I can't use them. Do you know whether exists something like what i'm searching for?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Other than HTTP cookies, there's nothing in the protocol specification about forwarding headers. The client needs to implement this functionality.

Comment: Are there any popular clients that _do_?

Answer (score 32):

Put your data in the new url as an argument:

```
HTTP/1.x 302 Found
Location: /dock?data=asdf
```

or save it in cookies

```
HTTP/1.x 302 Found
Location: /dock
Set-Cookie: data=asdf
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what cookies are used for. You can set it for the browser session and invalidate it after the next request.

Comment: That doesn't work so great if the redirects span different domains.

Comment: Or if you use stateless requests.