# How to redirect to another web service with data and header in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating rest web service using express nodejs framework. I want to navigate to second.js page from first.js and need to send data and header to it.

first.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");

var router = express.Router();

var options = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3000",
  path: "/second",
  method: "POST"
};

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  http.request(options);
});

module.exports = router;
```

second.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Hello");
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
app.use("/first", first);
app.use("/second", second);
```

I tried like above but it doesn't navigate to second.js web service. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not performing a redirection. You are actually making a call from within the first endpoint to a second endpoint and acting more like a proxy.

A redirection is performed by calling res.redirect as defined in the express documentation at http://expressjs.com/en/api.html (Search for res.redirect). A redirection returns a HTTP redirect response that the users browser will follow to a new URL. Unfortunately, redirections do not allow headers to be passed and it will be executed as a GET call(This is what redirections are designed for.).  You can include whatever query params you want in the URL though and set cookies (refer to [How to forward headers on HTTP redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969709/how-to-forward-headers-on-http-redirect))

Comment: Thanks Deadron. I am trying to use POST now. I am sending like `var options = { host: config.host, port: config.port, path: "/second", body: JSON.stringify({ foo: "foo" }), method: "POST" };` but not getting in second.js `console.log(req.body);` I am getting empty object {}

Comment: If you are having issues using the http lib I suggest you make a new question. As it is, the code you posted is not even reading the response from the call to http.request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `POST` in your request

But only set up `GET` on your second endpoint

Comment: I tried with GET also but not working. it keeps spinning wheel and getting Abort / timeout when I try "http://localhost:3000/first"

Comment: @Nancy That's because you are not sending a message back in `first`, you should send you response after you finish the http request

Comment: Thanks. I want to send the dynamic data into header. Do you know how to send ?

Comment: I am sending like `var options = {
  host: config.host,
  port: config.port,
  path: "/second",
  body: JSON.stringify({ foo: "foo" }),
  method: "POST"
};` but not getting in second.js   `console.log(req.body);` I am getting empty object {}