# Returning redirect from Flask to S3 doesn't download file

Tags: python, redirect, amazon-s3, flask

I need to redirect to an S3 URL while setting some extra S3-related headers. The Flask route is returning a page with `Redirecting to <url>` and a clickable link, and the browser doesn't automatically redirect. Why isn't the redirect working?

```
@app.route("/download/<token>")
def download(token):
    ...
    response = redirect(download_url)
    response.headers = generate_s3_headers(key, md5)
    return response
```

I can download the file successfully using Requests.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a compound problem. The immediate issue is that you're overwriting the `Location` header. However, if you fix that, [headers aren't preserved when following redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969709/how-to-forward-headers-on-http-redirect), so S3 won't get the headers.

If you need to serve a resource from S3 with special headers, you need to download and pass on that file through your app, instead of redirecting users directly to it.

```
headers = generate_s3_headers(key, md5)
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
response = app.response_class(r.iter_content())
response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment')
return response
```

---

The following is an explanation of why overriding the `Location` header breaks the redirect, but isn't the solution to your specific issue.

A redirect response includes the `Location` header. This is how the browser knows where to go next. `redirect` sets that header as well as generating a link in case the browser doesn't follow it. You're completely replacing all the headers though, removing `Location`. Use `headers.extend` to add your extra headers, rather than replacing them completely.

```
response = redirect(download_url)
response.headers.extend(generate_s3_headers(key, md5))
return response
```