# Can I retrieve the headers of a request or its content in VueJS?

Tags: django, vue.js, cas

I need to redirect my django app to my VueJS app, and I would like to forward information from one to other.

I can not see how I retrieve the headers request or the content request from an input request.

Edit :

The use case is :

- the user calls a VueJS page, we hasn't access token and refresh token,
- the app redirects the user to CAS website with the Django app in the "service" query param,
- CAS redirects the user to django app with "ticket" in query param,
- Django app uses the ticket for user connection and redirects the user to VueJS page.

And my problem is, how the Django app can give the access token and the refresh token in this last redirection to the VueJS app to save in storage ?

Comment: Could you provide some additional context about your use case?  E.g., is this a redirection for a login?  Forwarding headers during redirection is a client (browser) question, and is not typically allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forward headers on HTTP redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969709/how-to-forward-headers-on-http-redirect)

Comment: @Jay yes, it is. The use case is : the user calls a VueJS page, we hasn't access token and refresh token, the app redirects the user to CAS website with the Django app in the "service" query param, CAS redirects the user to django app with "ticket" in query param, Django app use the ticket for user connection, and redirects the user to VueJS page. And my problem is, how the Django app can give the access token and the refresh token in this last redirection.