# Spring boot returns 403 although i have admin authority

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-security, jwt

I came up with this issue when i added `/admin` endpoint to `antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")`
it simply won't make a **GET** request to `/admin` and return `200` it returns `403` instead

**Note:** i'm using JWT as an extra layer of authentication.

This is my security config

```java
httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/health", "/authority", "/dashboard", "/users/login", "/logoutUser", "/manageEvents", "/manageAeds", "/manageReports",
  "/charts", "/error", "/profile", "/authenticate/**", "/login", "/403", "/userProfile", "/deleteAed", "/users/add").permitAll()
 .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
 .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/error_css/**", "/scss/**", "/vendor/**").permitAll()
 .anyRequest().authenticated().and().
exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and()
 .sessionManagement()
 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

> By moving it to `permit.All()` it will work but it's not the case here.

This is where i handle the redirect inside `@Controller`

```java
@GetMapping("/authority")
public String getAuth(HttpServletResponse response) {

 if (jwt == null) {
  return "redirect:/login";
 }
 if (jwtTokenUtil.isTokenExpired(jwt)) {
  return "redirect:/login?token=expired";
 }
 response.addHeader("Auth", "Bearer " + jwt);

 System.out.println(loggedinUser.getRoles());

 if (loggedinUser != null) {
  if (loggedinUser.getRoles().equalsIgnoreCase("TILEFONITIS")) {
   return "redirect:/dashboard"; //will redirect
  } else if (loggedinUser.getRoles().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
   System.out.println("Admin");
   return "redirect:/admin"; //won't redirect
  } else if (loggedinUser.getRoles().equalsIgnoreCase("GUEST")) {
   return "redirect:/403"; // will redirect
  } else {
   return "redirect:/dashboard"; // will redirect
  }
 } else {
  return "redirect:/login";
 }

}
```

and this is my `/admin` inside `@Controller` which is never called.

```java
@GetMapping("/admin")
public String getAdmin(HttpServletResponse response) {
 if (jwt == null) {
  return "redirect:/login";
 }
 if (jwtTokenUtil.isTokenExpired(jwt)) {
  return "redirect:/login?token=expired";
 }
 response.addHeader("Auth", "Bearer " + jwt);

 System.out.println("jwt" + jwt);

 return "admin";

}
```

> The odd thing is that with **Postman** i get redirected!

What am i missing here?

---

Edit: The first call is at `/authenticate/web` where i tell spring i'm authenticated

```java
authenticationManager
.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getUsername(), auth.getPassword()));
```

---

Edit 2:

To make things even clearer:

*Visiting from **web***, flow:

1. POST `/authenticate/web`
2. redirect with `.js` to  `/authority` (GET)
3. Won't redirect to `/admin` (GET) -> 403

*Visiting from **Postman***, flow:

1. POST `/authenticate/web`
2. Get the `JWT` and include it in headers and make a GET to `/authority`
3. I'm seeing the **admin** template. -> 200

That's really odd, i add the `jwt` every time with `response.addHeader` on the **web** flow .

---

**Update:**

- These are the response headers from postman:

[image]

plus the `JWT` .

- Response headers from the web

[image]

Although now i noticed i get **302** from the web instead of a **200**

and as you can see `admin` page is **403**

[image]

---

**Update 2:**

I've managed to break down a few things,
first of all

- by having a `httpSecurity.addFilterBefore` on my security
  configuration means spring will look for the `JWT` and add a filter before the position of the specified filter class
- authorities are correctly assigned to users, so there is no issue
  there
- i changed `hasAuthority()` to `hasRole()`

If you get the **current user** you can automatically access it's authority as shown below

```java
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
System.out.println("Principal: "+auth.getPrincipal());
System.out.println("Authorities: "+auth.getAuthorities());
```

> Because the `authentication` is overriden by the `jwt filter` this
> means i will only manage to get a user only if the request header
> contains the valid `jwt`

this is why it worked from `postman` but not from the `web`.

---

Another issue is that in my controller i'm trying to add the `jwt` on the `response`  header which will be added to it only when the controller finishes it's job, i can't get in the very next line the user principal becuase there is no `jwt` to it's request header.

This screenshot represents a web call and the call from postman where both access `/authority` endpoint.

[image]

- From postman you see `ADMIN` as an authority
- But from the web i have a `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`

So i have two options to solve this:

1. Add it to the request header.
2. Protect `REST` endpoints with `JWT` and use default spring security (`hasRole()` etc) for the web part.

Comment: Show your token. Generally, with OAuth you'll be using `scope_ADMIN` as your authority name.

Comment: you mean  my custom endpoint for generating & authenticating the user?

Comment: No, I literally mean the JWT you're using to authenticate and authorize. Specifically, Spring Security is going to be looking for OAuth scopes, and those are mapped into authorities named `scope_<scopename>`.

Comment: that's one of many `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJuaWNrc3Rlcmc5IiwiZXhwIjoxNTkyNDI2NTE4LCJpYXQiOjE1OTIzOTA1MTh9.cgT3ZjZxEFr__e_Woyouw9M86uoCFKWFTDahxTXXOP4`

Comment: should i include `JwtUtil` and `JwtRequestFilter` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error , i managed to break down a few things and make the security work with a `JWT` as well as the default spring **authentication**.

In order for it to work i had to change entirely my `SecurityConfig` , and alter it to `MultipleSecurity`.

This is how Multiple Security works:

with `@Order(1)` annotation the security configuration is marked as the first thing to look for.

```java
@Order(1)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
  return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
   .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/api/authenticate/android").permitAll()
   .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().sessionManagement()
   .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
   .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
 }

}
```

- `@Order(1)` JWT
- `@Order(2)` default spring security

```java
@Order(2)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/web/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
   .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/redirect")
   .and().logout()
   .permitAll();
 }

}
```

What we basically say with these configurations is:

1. Look for a `JWT` at `/api/**`
2. Look for authorities at `/web/**`

So all the `/web` endpoints like `/web/admin` will now require `authorities` and not a `JWT` !

and all sensitive information from `/api/**` will require a `JWT`

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable the developer tools in your browser and capture the request and response headers of  `GET  /authority` from web. ie 2nd step of your web flow
2. Capture the request and response headers of  `GET  /authority` from postman. ie. 2nd step of your postman flow
3. Compare them (or post them here)

**Update based on screenshots posted**

Visiting from web:

1. `POST /authenticate/web`                  - this is success
2. redirect with .js to `GET /authority` - *this is also a success because it did it's job of redirecting it to `/admin`*.
   (response from authority redirects the browser to `/admin` so no issue here)
3. auto redirected request  to `/admin` fails with 403 (because as expected there is nobody add the jwt header to request as it is not a cookie or it is not part of the query param of the redirected url or some session session is maintained) (This is correct expected behaviour). See this question. [How to forward headers on HTTP redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969709/how-to-forward-headers-on-http-redirect)

Visiting from Postman:

1. `POST /authenticate/web`  this is success
2. Get the JWT and include it in headers and make a GET to /authority
3. Postman redirects it to `/admin` like in web flow
   (Postman retains the original jwt headers and forwards it to redirected url too but it shouldn't be doing it)

**Summary**

In summary, postman and web are behaving differently on redirect.i.e on a redirect, postman sends the original headers (in your case, it is jwt) and browser does not retain original http headers.

So you have to redesign  your application. 
For example,

1. you can capture the response from `/authority` endpoint  in javascript and manually forward it to `/admin` with http header
2. or may be as cookies. Because it will sent automatically even on redirect

Comment: both contain my valid `JWT` at response headers, i'll update my question with them

Comment: @phill-alexakis, as you can see the issue is not redirect in the web flow. Actually it also redirected to ```/admin``` endpoint using ```302``` status code. So now the question is why the redirected request ```/admin``` endpoint succeeds in postman and fails in web.

Comment: @phill-alexakis to understand that, can you capture all your request headers again from both postman and web. I.e you have the screenshot capturing the response headers of ```admin``` from web. But you didn't capture the request headers.  I am pretty sure there is something different in the request headers of ```/admin``` (note the issue is not ```authority``` endpoint because in both flows, it did the redirect to ```/admin```)

Comment: yes i added it, but i dont't see a `JWT` meaning the controller in not called to assign it

Comment: So you can see why the ```/admin``` is failing in webflow, because there is no jwt http header sent in http request.   Are you manually adding the jwt header in postman when sending to ```/admin```?

Comment: By using postman the controller is somehow called and then assigns the `JWT`. From the web the controller is not called as a result not `JWT` is set at response headers

Comment: responding to your summary , i'll try to forward the header manually , but there is no template for authority to be run to = no JavaScript to include at `/authority` , any ideas ?

Comment: if you take a look at `/admin` endpoint , when it's called, i add the `response header` , but that endpoint is not called with the `redirect:/admin` when `/admin`  has `has.Authority()` , again postman works , web doesn't

Comment: what you add is response header so the response to the browser has it as response header. But now browser  needs to make a new redirected request. And there is no requirement on browser to copy the response header to the redirected request

Comment: sure but, why with all other endpoints from the web are working fine?

Comment: None of auto redirect endpoint that requires jwt token would have worked from browser. Can you point which endpoint worked?

Comment: yes, all the endpoints included at `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(...).permitAll()` , (like `/authority` ) the logic goes as follows, when `/something` is called goes into the controller and get's the token to it's `HttpServletResponse` , so when the web renders it , the `request header` will contain the `JWT` but when it's at `.hasAuthority()` it won't ! but it will from postman! i think im losing my mind :D

Comment: I believe it has to do more with the `authentication` part rather than the `token`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your ```spring-security``` config. Issue in your design is that you store them as response headers which doesn't  get copied on redirect. You can store them as cookies instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Spring Security suggest mappings which are secured as to come before unsecured mappings, In this case,

.antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")

has to come before unsecured mappings("/","/authority" and others), In the Authorization part, this might be causing the problem.

Comment: That's not the case...with Postman by following the flow i get authenticated and admin is returned , through web though it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

```
.antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
```

Instead of `"/admin"` use `"/admin/**"` it works

Comment: it doesn't , `/admin` is 403 , why should `/admin/something` return 200?

Comment: `System.out.println(loggedinUser.getRoles());` It prints..??

Comment: .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") .. as `ROLE_` is the default Prefix you can use it or `ADMIN` can grant permission

https://www.journaldev.com/8748/spring-security-role-based-access-authorization-example

helps you

Comment: i know it can grand permission like this, although it does with just `ADMIN` but not from web only by calling it from `postman`

Comment: httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authority").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
 .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
 .exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);