# Redirecting with header and token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to login a user using jwt. when the users signs in a token is generated and I set a header
`res.header('Authorization', token);`
then i redirect to another route with a middleware to verify the token but  `req.header('Authorization');` is undefined in the middleware .if I send the user's token with postman header `Authorization: <user's token copied from database>`
it works but not with redirecting.  can someone point me my fault ? thank you

route with middleware

```
app.get("/home", verifyToken, async (req, res) => { // buraya auth ekle üye olmayan göremesin

    try {
        const tweets = await User.getAllTweets()
        console.log("--> ", req.token)
        res.render("home", { allTweets: tweets })
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.send(e)
    }
})
```

redirecting route

```
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    const user_email = req.body.email
    const user_password = req.body.password
    const user = new User({ email: user_email, password: user_password })

    try {
        // const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, "harrypotterbetterthanlotr")
        res.header('Authorization', token);
        console.log(token === res.getHeader("Authorization"));
        user.tokens.push(token)
        await user.save()
        await user.sendMail(user.email)
        res.redirect("/home")
     
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(501).redirect("/signup")
    }

})
```

middleware verifyToken.js

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization');
        console.log("token", token);
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "harrypotterbetterthanlotr")
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error("User not found")
        }
        req.token = token;
        req.user = user
        // Next middleware
        next();

    } catch (e) {
        // Forbid the route
        console.log("Authorization", req.header("authorization"));
        console.log("req token", req.token);
        // console.log("req header", header);
        res.status(401).send(e)

    }

}

module.exports = verifyToken
```

Comment: Maybe this article help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969709/how-to-forward-headers-on-http-redirect